# ember simple auth session, ember data, and passing a Authorization header

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

I have a working oauth2 authentication process where I get an access token (eg from facebook) using ember simple auth, send it to the back end which calls fb.me() and then uses JWT to create a token. This token is then sent back to the ember app, which then has to send it with every server request, include those requests made by ember-data.

I also need to have this token available after a browser reload.

I have tried many options, where I set a property 'authToken' on the session - I believe that this uses local storage to persist the authenticated session.

But I always seem to have trouble with coordinating the retrieval of this token - either I don't have access to the session, or the token is no longer on the session, or I can't change the ember data headers.

Does anyone have a working simple example of how this can be done - I think it should be easy, but I'm obviously missing something!

Thanks.

**Update**

The only thing I've been able to get working is to use torii as shown below, but the session content is still lost on refresh - I can see its still authenticated, but its lost the token I set here. So I'm still looking for a real solution.

```
   authenticateWithGooglePlus: function () {
      var self = this;
      this.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:torii', 'google-oauth2')
        .then(function () {
          resolveCodeToToken(self.get('session'), self);
        });
    }
```

resolveCodeToToken gets the bearer token from the server, sets it on the session and then transitions to the protected page:

```
function resolveCodeToToken(session, route) {
  var authCode = session.content.authorizationCode;
  var type = session.content.provider.split('-')[0];
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:4200/api/1/user/auth/' + type,
    data: {authCode: authCode}
  }).done(function (response) {
    // todo handle invalid cases - where user is denied access eg user is disabled
    session.set('authToken', response.token);
    route.transitionTo('activity', moment().format('DDMMYYYY'));
  });
}
```

And I have a custom authorizer for putting the token (stored in the session) on every request:

```
import Base from 'simple-auth/authorizers/base';

export default Base.extend({
  authorize: function(jqXHR, requestOptions) {
    var accessToken = this.get('session.content.authToken');
     if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated') && !Ember.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
       jqXHR.setRequestHeader('Authorization', accessToken);
     }
  }
});
```

I'm not sure why this.get('session.content.authToken') would be undefined after a refresh, I thought by default the session was persisted in local storage. The fact that it is authenticated is persisted, but thats useless without the token since the server will reject calls to protected endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to implement your own [custom authenticator](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authenticator) that first gets a token from Facebook and then sends that to your own server to exchange it for a token for your app. Once you have that you get authorization of ember-data requests as well as session persistence etc. for free.

Have a look at this example: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/7-multiple-external-providers.html

Comment: Thanks for answering - I thought I could use the torii authenticators (I had all that working) instead of implementing custom ones. Thats okay though, I can use the custom ones from your code there. BUT, how is the 'Authorization' token passed with all subsequent ajax requests? What I've got now has the same problem - the authorization header is not set... thanks

Comment: where I said "'Authorization' token" I really meant "'Authorization' HEADER" (which is the bearer token returned by my server and the token my server checks for on every request to a protected url)

Comment: ah, is that done by a custom authorizer? https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#implementing-a-custom-authorizer

Comment: OMG, I have it working now. I implemented a custom authorizer as documented and set the header using the token I put in the session. Last remaining issue is that even though I'm using local storage (just the defaults), the session content does not survive a browser reload. Don't know whats going on there.

Comment: So, is it the case that I can't use torii because there is no way to hook in to call my server to convert the accessToken into a bearer token? I'm not sure what the use case for this could ever really be?

Comment: If the session doesn't survive a reload you probably haven't implemented the authenticator's `restore` method correctly - see the API docs. If you want to use the torii authenticator and convert the token acquired by that with your own server you'd need to subclass the torii authenticator and add that conversion logic in the subclass.

Comment: Sigh, this drama is far from over. Now I've implemented a custom authenticator and authorizer FB doesn't want to work (won't popup the auth window and displays no error anywhere) and google always rejects the access token with 'invalid_grant'. This stuff is just wasting hours of time.

Comment: Is there an example of how to load the FB api when using an ember cli project? In the example you linked above you just put <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> in the page, just I assume thats not going to work with ember-cli ? At least, FB.getLoginStatus() does absolutely nothing for me now.

Comment: Here is a new ember app with simple auth, custom authenticator for facebook: https://github.com/prule/ember-auth-spike - seems to get the access token from FB okay, and put it in the session, but when reloading the page its gone... I'm inspecting the session content via the chrome ember extension. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something though.

Comment: make sure that the access token is persisted to `localStorage` after you logged in and that after reloading the authenticator's `restore` method is called with the correct data and actually returns a resolving promise.

Comment: After getting it working on a clean new project I just had to end up ripping the authentication code out and replacing it. It wasn't very clean anymore from trying so many things and also having the torii stuff in there. I did have a bit of a problem too with the server code - code I had for swapping the token used to work when I was using torii but I had to change the FB endpoint my server was using with this current code. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: I'm hoping to find time to put this experience to good use and publish a repo with both the working ember application and the server component (to exchange the token) so other newbies like myself have something to start with. I'll put it in github hopefully in the next week or two.

Comment: Please remove outdated question/answer. The link you added is broken.